# Scala match/case statement when matching Java Interfaces

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I'm using the Scala `match/case` statement to match an interface of a given java class. I want to be able to check if a class implements a combination of interfaces. The only way I can seem to get this to work is to use nested `match/case` statements which seems ugly.

Lets say I have a PersonImpl object which implements Person, Manager and Investor. I want to see if PersonImpl implements both Manager and Investor. I should be able to do the following:

```
person match {
  case person: (Manager, Investor) =>
    // do something, the person is both a manager and an investor
  case person: Manager =>
    // do something, the person is only a manager
  case person: Investor =>
    // do something, the person is only an investor
  case _ =>
    // person is neither, error out.
}
```

The `case person: (Manager, Investor)` just doesn't work. In order to get it to work I have to do the following which seem ugly.

```
person match {
  case person: Manager = {
    person match {
      case person: Investor =>
        // do something, the person is both a manager and investor
      case _ =>
        // do something, the person is only a manager
    }
  case person: Investor =>
    // do something, the person is only an investor.
  case _ =>
    // person is neither, error out.
}
```

This is just plain ugly. Any suggestions?

Comment: `case person: Manager with Investor` ought to work. What happens when you call an `Investor` method on these objects that you say are only `Manager`?

Comment: It would be great if you could either accept an answer or tell us what other things you would like to know about this topic.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
case person: Manager with Investor => // ...
```

`with` is used for other scenarios where you might want to express type intersection, e.g. in a type bound:

```
def processGenericManagerInvestor[T <: Manager with Investor](person: T): T  = // ...
```

By the way — **not that this is recommended practice**, but — you can always test it like this as well: `if (person.isInstanceOf[Manager] && person.isInstanceOf[Investor]) ...`.

---

**Edit:** this works well for me:

```
trait A
trait B
class C

def printInfo(a: Any) = println(a match {
  case _: A with B => "A with B"
  case _: A => "A"
  case _: B => "B"
  case _ => "unknown"
})

def main(args: Array[String]) {
  printInfo(new C)               // prints unknown
  printInfo(new C with A)        // prints A
  printInfo(new C with B)        // prints B
  printInfo(new C with A with B) // prints A with B
  printInfo(new C with B with A) // prints A with B
}
```

Comment: I just tested case person: Manager with Investor and unfortunately it didn't work. It catches persons that implement only Manager as well as persons that implement both. Is this a bug?

Comment: Funny. I've added a short example in my answer that works well for me with Scala 2.8.1. Which version are you using?

Comment: You are correct. I just ran your example and it worked. In my case I'm not using traits as the "class" is a java and is implementing an interface, but I don't think that should matter.

Comment: Because my situation isn't pure scala, its a scala, java mixture, here is what I had to do to get it to work.

    person match {
      case person **if (person.isInstanceOf[Manager] && person.isInstanceOf[Investor])** =>
        // do something, the person is both a manager and an investor
      case person: Manager =>
        // do something, the person is only a manager
      case person: Investor =>
        // do something, the person is only an investor
      case _ =>
        // person is neither, error out.
    }

I still don't like this but its better than nested case statements.

Comment: It works with me even if I define `A`, `B` and `C` in Java. Sounds like a bug to me. Are you compiling the Java classes yourself?

Comment: I'm using maven to compile both java and scala. Java is compiled first as scala relies on java. The version of scala is 2.8.1

Comment: "Because my situation isn't pure scala, its a scala, java mixture..." to head off some misinformation, that's irrelevant.  If it isn't working it's a bug.  And though bugs are all too common, in this case I suspect user error because I know that code works in the situation you are describing.

Comment: @user523078 A [short, self-contained, correct example](http://sscce.org) would help narrow down the problem. The one explanation that occurs to me is that erasure may be an issue if `Manager` and `Investor` are abstract types or type parameters.